# How to tell using XPath if an element is present and non empty?

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

I have an input XML something on this line:

```
<Holding id="12">
    <Policy>
        <HoldingForm tc="1">Individual</HoldingForm>
        <PolNumber>848433</PolNumber>
        <LineOfBusiness tc="1">Life</LineOfBusiness>
        <CarrierCode>67644</CarrierCode>
    </Policy>
</Holding>
```

My manipulation on this XML depends on if `<PolNumber>` (its an optional element in schema) has a value or not. I'm using Mule 3.3 `xpath` evaluator to do this and my XPath expression looks this:

```
<expression-filter expression="#[xpath('//acord:Holding/acord:Policy/acord:PolNumber').text != empty]"/>
```

This works fine as long as `<PolNumber>` element is present or `<PolNumber/>` is empty element. But if `<PolNumber>` is absent, above expression throws exception.

I tried using [XPath boolean](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean) function but it returns `true` for `<PolNumber/>`. Is there a better way of checking if an element is present and non-empty?

EDIT:

This is the configuration of namespace manager in my mule config

```
<xm:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <xm:namespace prefix="acord" uri="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" />
    <xm:namespace prefix="soap" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
</xm:namespace-manager>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Use**:

```
boolean(//acord:Holding/acord:Policy/acord:PolNumber/text()[1])
```

this produces `true()` if `//acord:Holding/acord:Policy/acord:PolNumber` has a first text-node child, and `false()` otherwise.

**Do note**: This is more efficient than counting all text-node children just to compare the count with 0.

Comment: I agree this is better than counting all text-node children but even this solution is not full-proof. this xpath will return true for `<Holding><Policy><PolNumber></PolNumber><Policy></Holding>`. I don't know how to show a new line in comment but my intent was to have new line character between `<PolNumber>` and `</PolNumber>`

Comment: @Learner, This is straight-forward: `boolean(//acord:Holding/acord:Policy/acord:PolNumber/text()[normalize-space()][1])`

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. I don't have exposure with xpath, all this is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `boolean(...)` for checking if it's empty, but make sure to *look inside* the element.

```
boolean(//PolNumber/node())
```

This also works if other nodes are contained. If you want to limit to text nodes, replace `node()` by `text()`. You could want to use `//text()` instead, then the query will also yield true for text nodes inside other child elements of `<PolNumber/>`.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer in my eyes. `boolean(//a/node())` on `<a></a>` gives false. Whereas `<a><b/></a>` gives true. Try it out here: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. `boolean(//a/text()[1])` yields false under both those scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm a bit late here, but answers are a bit confusing.
This one will always returns false when text is blank or with spaces but no chars.

```
boolean//Holding/Policy/PolNumber/child/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using `count` to get the number of text nodes:

```
<expression-filter
    expression="#[xpath('count(//Holding/Policy/PolNumber/child::text())') != 0]"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. `No Such Function {http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core}:count (org.jaxen.UnresolvableException)
  org.jaxen.SimpleFunctionContext:127` exception is thrown for count function.

Comment: I changed above expression to `<expression-filter
    expression="#[xpath('fn:count(//acord:Holding/acord:Policy/acord:PolNumber)') != 0]"/>` and that worked, however, for `<PolNumber/>` count is non zero just like `boolean` function

Comment: Strange you have to prefix with `fn`. Edit your question and show how is your namespace manager configured please.

Comment: Thanks, I think `includeConfigNamespaces` is what's screwing the default namespace and forces to prefix with `fn`. Do you really need it?

Comment: I've reviewed by answer to count the number of text child nodes in PolNumber. You may need to prefix with `fn:` in your config.

Comment: I don't need `includeConfigNamespaces` attribute really. Removing it caused function to work without `fn` prefix. Thanks for pointing that. Don't think I'd be able to catch it.

Comment: Now, with text child nodes, it works for all the scenarios. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

How about `expression="#[?xpath('//acord:Holding/acord:Policy/acord:PolNumber').text != empty]"` ? This should work in in all situations